# codeigniter site_model Severity: Notice error what is wrong with this line?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a newbie with codeigniter and trying to learn crud in codeigniter..
My site controller is :

```
class Site extends CI_Controller 
{
    function index()
    {
        $data = array();
        if($query = $this->site_model->get_records())
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }   
        $this->load->view('options_view', $data);
    }
```

And my site_model is :

```
class Site_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
    }


    function get_records()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('data');
        return $query->result();
    }

    function add_record($data) 
    {
        $this->db->insert('data', $data);
        return;
    }

    function update_record($data) 
    {
        $this->db->where('id', 12);
        $this->db->update('data', $data);
    }

    function delete_row()
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->db->delete('data');
    }

}
```

I made $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
When i try to check the site I get error :

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Site::$site_model

Filename: controllers/site.php

Line Number: 9
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the model:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller 
{
    //you also need the constructor
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Site_model');
    }
    function index()
    {
        $data = array();
        //now you can use it
        if($query = $this->site_model->get_records())
        {
            $data['records'] = $query;
        }   
        $this->load->view('options_view', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your `site_model` before you can access it. You can manually load it like this:

```
function index()
{
    // Load the model...
    $this->load->model('site_model');

    $data = array();
    if($query = $this->site_model->get_records())
    {
        $data['records'] = $query;
    }   
    $this->load->view('options_view', $data);
}
```

If you are using the model in more than one method in your class, you should load the model in the class' constructor:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    // Load the model...
    $this->load->model('site_model');
}
```

Alternatively, you can [autoload](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#auto_load_model) the model (via `config/autoload.php`) if you're going to need it throughout your application:

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Models
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['model'] = array('model1', 'model2');
|
*/

$autoload['model'] = array('site_model');
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in two ways. Both Colin and Radashk method works. If I use Radashk method , it is enough to write the function on the top. If I use Colin's method , I have to use  `$this->load->model('site_model');` for each of delete and create methods.

Other option is `$autoload['model'] = array('site_model');`

Thanks for your replies. I hope. information may help anyone else

Comment: Consider autoloading the model if you're going to need it throughout the application.

Comment: hmmm , is it true $autoload['model'] = array('site_model'); ?

Comment: Yes, that's how you would autoload the model. In the same way that loading the model in the constructor saves you from loading it in each individual method, autoloading the model saves you from having to load the model in multiple places throughout your application (multiple controllers, etc.)