# Message: Undefined property: Site::$Site_model - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am auto loading the library site_model already in autoload config, and this is the error I am getting:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Site::$Site_model

Filename: controllers/site.php

Line Number: 16

Fatal error: Call to a member function add_record() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/BLOCK/application/controllers/site.php on line 16
```

controller:

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller {

function index(){

    $this->load->view('option_view');
}

function create(){

    $data = array(
        'subject' => $this->input->post('subject'),
        'body' => $this->input->post('body')
    );

    $this->Site_model->add_record($data);
    $this->index();

}

}


?>
```

model:

```
<?php

class Site_model extends CI_Model {

function get_records()

{
    $query = $this->db->get('items');
    return $query->result();
}

function add_record()
{
    $this->db->insert('items', $data);
    $return;
}

function update_record()
{
    $this->db->where('id', 1);
    $this->db->update('items', $data);

}

function delete_record()
{
    $this->db->where('id', $this->url->segment(3));
    $this->db->delete('items');

}

}





?>
```

and the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>option_view</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
label {display:block;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Create</h2>
<?php echo form_open('site/create'); ?>

<p>
    </label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
</p>

<p>
    </label for="body">Body</label>
    <input type="text" name="body" id="body">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">    
</p>
<?php echo form_close();?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What do you guys reckon?

Much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter site_model Severity: Notice error what is wrong with this line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729649/codeigniter-site-model-severity-notice-error-what-is-wrong-with-this-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$this->load->model('Site_model'); # <- add this
$this->Site_model->add_record($data);
```

Comment: Thanks I was autoloading the model already in the config but was missing a capital S !!

Answer (score 4):

Your code is nice....but you forgotted only simple thing.You forgotted to give the below in your Controller "__Construct()"

```
$this->load->model('your modelname');
```

That's it.everythng is well defind.

Answer (score 2):

Add a constructor. Then it will help to call the model.

```
<?php
class some_controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('site_model');

    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('your_view');
    }
    function create()
    {
        $data = array(
            'test1' => $this->input->post('test1'),
            'test2' => $this->input->post('test2')
            );
        $this->site_model->add($data);
        $this->index();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

add "Site_model" on `config-autoload.php` as below:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Site_model');
```